# Trying to find difference between two 2*2 matrices. I have this code but it comes up with invalid values

Tags: java

```
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Welcome to matrix subtracting!");
    
    System.out.println("Enter the number of rows in matrix 1:");
    
    int mat1_rows = keyboard.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Enter the number of columns in matrix 1:");
    
    int mat1_cols = keyboard.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Enter the number of rows of matrix 2:");
    
    int mat2_rows = keyboard.nextInt();
    
    if(mat1_cols != mat2_rows) 
    {
        System.out.println("Dimension mismatch! Cannot subtract these matrices!");
        
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    System.out.println("Enter the number of columns of matrix 2:");
    
    int mat2_cols = keyboard.nextInt();
    
    int[][] matrix1 = new int[mat1_rows][mat1_cols];
    int[][] matrix2 = new int[mat2_rows][mat2_cols];

    
    for(int i = 0; i < mat1_rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < mat1_cols; j++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the matrix1 value at ("+i+", "+j+"):");
            
            matrix1[i][j] = keyboard.nextInt();
            
        }
    }
    
    //populate matrix2 with values
    
    for(int i = 0; i < mat2_rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < mat2_cols; j++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the matrix2 value at ("+i+", "+j+"):");
            
            matrix2[i][j] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
    }
    
    int sum = 0;
    
    int[][] differenceMatrix = new int[mat1_rows][mat2_cols];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < mat1_rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < mat2_cols; j++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < mat1_cols; k++)
            {
                sum = matrix1[i][k] - matrix2[k][j];
            }
            
            differenceMatrix[i][j]= sum;
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
    
    //print the difference matrix
    
    for(int i = 0; i < mat1_rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < mat2_cols; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(differenceMatrix[i][j]+"\t");
        }
        
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

When I apply this code, I am able to store all my matrice values into the number of columns and rows i want. But when I run the code, the subtraction is done wrong and does not equate to a true difference. Any suggestions? For example, if I were to enter 15 as (0,0), 25 as (0,1), 2 as (1,0) and 16 as (1,1) for my first matrix and subtract it with another matrix containing 2 as (0,0), 5 as (0,1), 15 as (1,0) and 2 as (1,1) the program output will = [13, 20, -13, 14] (in reading order left to right).

Comment: i had tried this but it also came up with random values and got me further from the true difference so I removed it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [**subtraction**](https://stattrek.com/matrix-algebra/matrix-addition.aspx) of two matrices is calculated as:

*Diff<sub>i,j</sub> = M1<sub>i,j</sub> - M2<sub>i,j</sub>*

that is, no third level loop is needed and the method may be implemented as simply as:

```java
public static int[][] diffMatrix(int[][] m1, int[][] m2) {
    // m1.cols == m2.rows
    int[][] res = new int[m1.length][m2.length];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m2.length; j++) {
            res[i][j]= m1[i][j] - m2[i][j];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Testing this method:

```java
int[][] m1  = {
    {15, 25},
    {2, 16}
};

int[][] m2 = {
    {2, 5},
    {15, 2}
};

int[][] diff = diffMatrix(m1, m2);

for(int[] row : diff) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

outputs:

```
[13, 20]
[-13, 14]
```